# Why does sound say it's working but isn't in windows 7 bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, macos, operating-systems, boot-camp, osx-yosemite

I recently installed windows 7 home premium in bootcamp on os x Yosemite. The sound driver is working and everything. The sound appears to be working. I don't hear anything though. I have the volume set to full. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried installing bootcamp support software ?

Comment: Yes, it installed automatically, but I'll see if there is a download on apple's website worth trying...

Comment: I found that the boot camp software had become corrupt after installing, I reinstalled it and it worked! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing loss of sound and other bugs because my boot camp support software had become corrupt, I reinstalled it and now it works great! You can find a download on Apple's website https://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/